# PhoneGap getPicture callback firing with a delay in Backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, backbone.js, cordova

I'm trying to use `getPicture()` to allow a user to select a photo/video when clicking a button in a Backbone view. Here's the relevant section in my view code:

```
    events: {
        "click .add-moment-media": "addMedia",
    },

    addMedia: function(e) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(this.successAddMedia, this.errorAddMedia, { 
            quality: 20,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA  
        })
    },

    successAddMedia: function(imageURI) {
        showAlert("Your photo has been uploaded!", "Your Photo"  + imageURI);
    },

    errorAddMedia: function(message) {
        showAlert("Failed because: " + message, "Failure");
    }
```

For testing purposes I'm simply trying to show an alert with the image's URI when successful.

**The problem:** when I press the button, a gallery appears as expected and I'm able to select a picture. When I return to the app, there's no alert -- no success alert, no error alert. However, if I click the button again, the alert that should have appeared *last time* appears, and the photo gallery appears on top of it. It's as if the `getPicture()` callback doesn't want to fire until the next time the button is pressed.

Here's the kicker: elsewhere in my app, I have `getPicture()` working like a charm (except it uses `PictureSourceType.CAMERA` instead of `PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`, and the line is not in a Backbone view) with the callbacks firing at the right time. If I copy and paste the working line of code in this view, the callbacks delay just like they do with the code above.

This is happening on Android. I'm not sure if there's some undocumented issue with PhoneGap and Backbone or something -- if anyone has any ideas on what might be wrong, I'd be thankful!

Comment: I have the same issue with ios. Did you have any luck figuring it out?